# User defined threads created are of type Native?

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee

I have one question regarding threading.When you create a thread in java using Callable interface or Runnable interface what threads get created native or green, do you have control of this or is it the JVM and the OS you use that determines this?

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads#Green_threads_in_the_Java_virtual_machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The language specification does not define the kind of threads to be used. The actual kind of threads depends on the JVM implementation and the underlying OS and hardware.

However, if you are using the HotSpot VM on regular computing hardware, you are very very very likely using native threads.

EDIT: The JVM does have a thread scheduler, but AFAIK, it delegates the actual scheduling the the OS. Early JVM implementations did the scheduling in the VM itself. The threads of your application are sharing the resources of the VM process.

Comment: :I am executing my java programme on Windows machine. That means any thread we created on the local java programe are closed to Native thread???

Comment: Yes, you are almost certainly using native threads in this case.

Comment: One more question is that all these threads are executing under oone java process?Is operating system is responsible for doing the scheduling of the thread or scheduling is done by JVM itself?

Comment: Please see the edit. Consider adding the additional questions to your post - it will make it clearer to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Green threads are in past, JVMs work only with native threads since 1.3

Answer (score 0):

In most JVMs threads are native, however JRockit has support "thin" threads and still not too old. In JRockit you can choose between `-Xthinthreads` and default `-Xnativethreads`

Answer (score -1):

Java threads are objects like any other Java objects. Threads are instances of class java.lang.Thread, or instances of subclasses of this class. In addition to being objects, java threads can also execute code.

let me brief you..

Green threads are scheduled by a virtual machine.

Native threads are scheduled by a operational system.

> Green threads are in past, JVMs work only with native threads since
>   1.3 which  Java virtual machine creates and manages Java threads using the operating system threads library

Comment: @Nira : So in other words thread if I am using the jvm on windows then thread that is been created on my local java programme are native threads. These threads are created with help of windows system threads library??????